# Crystal Reports - sum of report field error when inserted into report

Tags: crystal-reports

I've created a crystal report with a field issueSUM.LineTL in the detail section of the report.
This field returns the correct information per line.
I need to sum this field in the report footer and i have created a formula field - `Sum({IssueSum.LineTL})`.

I inserted this field and at report generation it comes up with an error: 
Error in formula `Sum({IssueSum.LineTL})`
The field name is not known

Please advise as to what could cause this

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have given wrong syntax in sum forumla, instead of creating a formula and writing the `sum()`. Right click on `issueSUM.LineTL` and go to insert summary and generate summary from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is just a typo here in your post, but your formula is `Sum({IssueSum.LineTL})` whereas your field is `issueSUM.LineTL`. That's a capital 'I' versus a lower-case 'i'. When creating formulas, double-clicking on the field in the field explorer window of the formula editor to insert a field will help you avoid such typos.
Other than that I agree with @Siva that right-clicking and choosing "Insert" -> "Summary" is a much easier and more reliable way to create summaries. Make sure to choose "Sum" as the type of summary from the choices available and put the summary in the report footer.